# Multiple pattern matching

Tags: regex

I'm trying print section of file between two regular expressions. The twist is that first expression can be either pattern 1, `Error:` or pattern 2 `FAILED` with the last expression being a fixed pattern (`----------`).

Example of section of file:

```
Line 01

10-10-16 22:23:34 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer ABC|£-336.95]
10-10-16 22:23:34 Error processing file information, Block 27.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 05

Line 06

Line 07

10-10-16 22:26:52 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer DEF|£-0.66]
10-10-16 22:26:52 Error processing file information, Block 37.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 11

Line 12

Line 13

20161010 22:28:25 File 6 FAILED... FILE11.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 16

Line 17

Line 18

10-10-16 22:31:30 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer JKL|£-155.88]
10-10-16 22:31:30 Error processing file information, Block 3.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 22

Line 23

Line 24

10-10-16 22:33:04 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer MNO|£-12.65]
10-10-16 22:33:04 Error processing file information, Block 9.
Line 27

Line 28

Line 29

20161010 22:35:41 File 7 FAILED... FILE12.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------

The output I'm looking for is below

10-10-16 22:23:34 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer ABC|£-336.95]
10-10-16 22:23:34 Error processing file information, Block 27.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-16 22:26:52 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer DEF|£-0.66]
10-10-16 22:26:52 Error processing file information, Block 37.
20161010 22:28:25 File 6 FAILED... FILE11.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------

10-10-16 22:31:30 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer JKL|£-155.88]
10-10-16 22:31:30 Error processing file information, Block 3.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-16 22:33:04 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer MNO|£-12.65]
10-10-16 22:33:04 Error processing file information, Block 9.
20161010 22:35:41 File 7 FAILED... FILE12.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I've managed to get is one or the other using this command:

```
cat FILE* | sed -n '/Error/,/------/p'  >> ${TEMP}/err.tmp

cat FILE* | sed -n '/FAILED/,/------/p' >> ${TEMP}/err.tmp
```

But my output is not in order the text appears in file:

```
10-10-16 22:23:34 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer ABC|£-336.95]
10-10-16 22:23:34 Error processing file information, Block 27.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-16 22:26:52 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer DEF|£-0.66]
10-10-16 22:26:52 Error processing file information, Block 37.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-16 22:31:30 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer JKL|£-155.88]
10-10-16 22:31:30 Error processing file information, Block 3.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
10-10-16 22:33:04 Error: Failed to update discount row [Customer MNO|£-12.65]
10-10-16 22:33:04 Error processing file information, Block 9.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
20161010 22:28:25 File 6 FAILED... FILE11.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
20161010 22:35:41 File 7 FAILED... FILE12.txt
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated as I've been searching online for a solution and haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/Error/||/Failed/,/----/' file
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Cool. Thank you.